# Import file from main src folder into nested folder

Tags: reactjs

**Goal** : I want to import my `reducer.js` file into my `Payment.js` file

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

I'm currently using `import { getBasketTotal } from '../reducer'` in my `Payment.js` file and I can't seem to get it working.

I know this is probably a simple issue but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: import { getBasketTotal } from '../../../reducer'

Comment: @polyglot can you please explain?

Comment: okay, It works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use '../' it will go one up in your directory, in your case in the components directory. Doing so again will take you to the src directory where 'reducer.js' exists. So the import will be

> import {getBasketTotal} from '../../reducer'